# Is RunClassConstructor guaranteed to run a type's static constructor only once?

Tags: c#, static-constructor

I'm calling the static ctor of a class using this code:

```
Type type;
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(type.TypeHandle);
```

Can this cause the cctor to be run twice?

Comment: RunClassConstructor doesn't. But CLR does! Type constructor guaranteed to run only once per AppDomain.

Comment: @StasBZ A correctly-split hair indeed, but for the benefit of those who choose to blur the [CLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime)/[BCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Libraries_(CLI)) distinction, the answer is... yes, it just works. As an aside, the elevation of this whole topic is a bit mysterious to me, considering how entirely trivial it is in *any* code—notwithstanding the CLR—to ensure single execution with a single simple [`cmpxchg`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) instruction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`RunClassConstructor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.runclassconstructor) runs the static constructor only once, even if you call it twice. Just try ;)

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
...

void Main()
{
    RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(typeof(Foo).TypeHandle);
    RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(typeof(Foo).TypeHandle);
    Foo.Bar();
}

class Foo
{
    static Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo");
    }

    public static void Bar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bar");
    }
}
```

This code prints :

> Foo
>   Bar

Comment: Is that true even if I call RunClassConstructor, _then_ use the class for the first time (which would usually cause the cctor to run)? And is that guaranteed? The MSDN does not provide any information.

Comment: Ah, ok, so it works in practice. Now if only some official paper would state that this is not going to be changed in the future...

Comment: BTW, I tested the code above with .NET 4.0, and there has been a few changes to the way types are initialized in .NET 4.0 (see Jon Skeet's blog post : http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/01/26/type-initialization-changes-in-net-4-0.aspx). So you might want to try it in 3.5

Comment: Yes, but I'd really like an official paper to make sure it's not going to be changed randomly. That's the only concern left.

Comment: I've tested it in 3.5 and the cctor is behaving correctly, even if the class is already initialized.

Comment: @Thomas Levesque - Updating broken link to Jon Skeet's blog post: http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/01/26/type-initialization-changes-in-net-4-0/

Comment: Be careful.  Calling RunClassConstructor on a derived type does not necessarily call it on the base type.  I had to call it recursively on Type.BaseType in order to get it to initialize the whole inheritance hierarchy.  I'm not sure if it mattered that the type I called it on didn't have any static constructors, but my goal was to call the base generic type's static constructor.